# Adding extra lines/spaces in source, *not* affecting semantics

Tags: formatting, line-breaking, vim, source

I'm editing a file with quite huge interleaves of text and formulas like this

```
lorem ipsums
\begin{align}
  foo & bar\\
  qux & rofl\\
      & toto
\end{align}
lorem ipsums
…
```

And I face a problem when I want my editor to indent/wrap the text of the `lorem ipsums`: it will think that a paragraph goes until the next blank line, which means that it will format the whole thing into a blurb like the following:

```
lorem ipsums \begin{align} foo & bar\\ qux & rofl\\ & toto \end{align} lorem ipsums …
```

which, you'll agree, is a lot less nice to read and edit.

I wonder if there is a way round this, so that I can insert lines around my formulas, without changing the semantics?

Maybe something like

```
lorem ipsums\slurp

\begin{align}
  foo & bar\\
  qux & rofl\\
      & toto
\end{align}
\slurp

lorem ipsums
…
```

Cheers.

Comment: I would suggest the best way to deal with this problem would be editor specific, rather than trying to gobble empty lines within tex. What editor are you using?

Comment: Ah. Just spotted the vim tag. Are you using the LaTeX suite? I'm surprised this doesn't deal with this properly already.

Comment: No, I'm not using LaTeX suite.  I just use plugins not specific to TeX (like snipmate) and the conceal mode of vim.  And also a plugin I wrote myself for real-time compilation and display.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your editor knows about comments, then the simplest method is to put a comment character on the blank lines:

```
lorem ipsums
%
\begin{align}
  foo & bar\\
  qux & rofl\\
      & toto
\end{align}
%
lorem ipsums
```

But this will only work if your editor knows not to break up comment lines.

**Update:** Although I think that the real answer is: use a formatter that's LaTeX-aware, here's three answers to the actual question.  This may not be very elegant, and it may break something elsewhere (I haven't tested it much).

```
\documentclass{article}
% \url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24786/86}
\let\savepar=\par
\def\restorepar{\let\par=\savepar}
\def\nopar{\let\par=\restorepar}

\long\def\igpar#1{}

% Equivalent to the above is:
%\makeatletter
%\let\igpar=\@gobble
%\makeatother

\makeatletter
\def\eatpar{\@ifnextchar\par{\@gobble}{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This is a paragraph.

This is the next paragraph.
This should be part of the previous one.

This is a paragraph.

This is the next paragraph.
\nopar

This should be part of the previous one.

This is a paragraph.

This is the next paragraph.
\igpar

This should be part of the previous one.

This is a paragraph.

This is the next paragraph.
\eatpar

This should be part of the previous one.

\end{document}
```

I recommend that these be on their own on a line.  Not only does that make it easier to remove them later, but also means that the spacing at the end of the previous line is preserved.

The first (`\nopar`) works by redefining `\par` so that the next occurrence of `\par` is effectively ignored.  So that it only works once, the next occurrence of `\par` also resets itself back to `\par` so that the *next* one will work as before.  The `\nopar` can actually occur anywhere, not just before the blank line.

The second (`\igpar`) simply gobbles its next argument.  As it is `\long`, it can gobble a `\par` with impunity.

The third (`\eatpar`) tests the next token to see if it is a `\par` or not.  If it is, it gobbles it.  If not, it leaves it alone.  This is probably the most robust.

All of them work because of how TeX treats blank lines.  When the *input* processor of TeX sees a blank line, it inserts a `\par` token in to the stream.  This means that the blank line gets replaced by a `\par` *before* any macro processing is done.  So in the internals of TeX, we can test for blank lines by testing against `\par`s.  Otherwise, we'd have to test for the newline character, and test to see if we got two in a row.

Comment: An editor smart enough not to break comments should be smart enough not to collect environments into a paragraph...

Comment: @Seamus: True, but if the editor doesn't have a specific LaTeX mode but can cope with code then this would be a halfway house.  (But I hadn't taken note of the [vim] tag, otherwise I probably wouldn't have posted.)

Comment: Inserting comments quite doesn't work, as it will still them make a mess of everything inside the environment; vim behaves as "do not format what's before and after the comment together, but don't stop formatting, keep going as far as you can."

Comment: @Axioplase: Not being a vim-user, I didn't know that.  So you really do need a blank line.

Comment: @Axioplase: I've updated my answer to provide a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Consider `\gobblepars`:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\gobblepars{%
    \@ifnextchar\par%
        {\expandafter\gobblepars\@gobble}%
        {}}
\makeatother
```

Notice that the recursive definition allows it to gobble more than just one par. So you should be able to get away with...

```
One paragraph. \gobblepars




More of that one paragraph.
```

Just make sure to put a space before the `\gobblepars`. Alternatively, you could modify `\gobblepars` to insert a space when it's done, like this:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\gobblepars{%
    \@ifnextchar\par%
        {\expandafter\gobblepars\@gobble}%
        { }}
\makeatother
```

*[ background: I originally posted about `\gobblepars` [elsewhere](http://phaseportrait.blogspot.com/2011/08/using-gobblepars-to-prevent-latex-from.html)... ]*