# Command that gobbles all following empty lines

Tags: macros, knitr

One distinction between `knitr` and `Sweave` is that the former forcibly inserts two empty lines in the generated TeX source for chunks that do not do any output.
I'm not sure if this [issue](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/231) is a bug or a feature, but for now I'm looking for a workaround.

The problem can be summarized as follows: `.Rnw` code like

```
a
<<q,echo=FALSE,results='hide'>>=
getwd()
@
b
```

produces LaTeX code like

```
a


b
```

where the space between `a` and `b` is not always desired. The best workaround that I found so far is to write

```
a\q{
<<q,echo=FALSE,results='hide'>>=
getwd()
@
}b
```

and define `\q` as a one-parameter command that expands to a single space. Is there a shorter way to achieve a similar result, perhaps without using braces and without affecting the line that starts with `b`?

**ADDED**: Is there a way to assign to a special character, say, `§`, the semantics of this command, so that the following will work:

```
a §
<<q,echo=FALSE,results='hide'>>=
getwd()
@
b
```

(Of course, a `knitr` way to achieve this would be most welcome, too.)

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24790/8057) seems related, but I haven't been able to get the `\eatpar` command to work. Would it eat two empty lines, too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following definition (taken from [this blog](http://phaseportrait.blogspot.com/2011/08/using-gobblepars-to-prevent-latex-from.html)) appears to work:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\gobblepars{%
    \@ifnextchar\par%
        {\expandafter\gobblepars\@gobble}%
        {}}
\makeatother
```

Then, I can write:

```
a \gobblepars
<<q,echo=FALSE,results='hide'>>=
getwd()
@
b
```

to achieve the desired result.