# Assign special semantics to a character

Tags: macros

When looking for a [Command that gobbles all following empty lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55914/8057), I wondered if it is possible to define a shortcut for this command consisting of one single character.

Is ist possible to assign to, say, the character `§` the special semantics that a certain command (say, `\fancystuff`) is executed?

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\fancystuff{\do\some\fancy\stuff\here}
% How to assign to § the semantics of \fancystuff ?

\begin{document}
    This is text. But the following character §
    gets fancy stuff done.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Search for "active character".

Comment: You could make the character active and then `\let` it be `\fancystuff`, I guess.

Comment: Done: http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=activechars . Thank you for the pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the input encoding is Latin-1, the byte which is represented by `§` is already active, so all you need to do is to change its meaning.

```
% -*- coding: latin-1 -*-
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\newcommand{\fancystuff}{\textit{Whatever}}
\protected\def§{\fancystuff}

\begin{document}
\section{The fancy § works also in section titles!}

Here's an example of §.

\end{document}
```

The `\protected\def` is to be sure the character is written as itself in the auxiliary files.

If you're using UTF-8 as encoding, the same result can be obtained with `newunicodechar`:

```
% -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\fancystuff}{\textit{Whatever}}
\newunicodechar{§}{\fancystuff}

\begin{document}
\section{The fancy §{} works also in section titles!}

Here's an example of §.

\end{document}
```

In this case `\protected\def§` would *not* work or, better, it would give wrong results. However the character will *not* be written as itself in the auxiliary files.

Whether using `\DeclareRobustCommand` or not depends on what `§` is supposed to do; if you don't plan to use it in "fragile" contexts, probably `\newcommand` is better.

Answer (score 3):

Since § is not an ASCII character, you could use Unicode.

Here § has code U+00A7 in Latin-1 Supplement codepage of Unicode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A7}{fancystuff}
\begin{document}
    §
\end{document}
```

This should print `fancystuff` or the result of any command you supply as the second argument to the `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` command.

Comment: Are there ways to achieve this with `inputenc` for, say, the @ character in the Latin-1 encoding?

Answer (score 0):

This is called "active character" in the TeX world. The procedure, as outlined in [this TeX FAQ article](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-activechars), can be summarized as follows:

- Make the charcter active
- `\def` it to do whatever you want

The following MWE achieves this (using @ instead of § as special character, to avoid encoding problems):

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand\fancystuff{\textbf{(pondering over fancy stuff)}}
\catcode`\@=\active
\def@{\fancystuff}

\begin{document}
  This is text. But the following character @
  gets fancy stuff done.
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of compilation]