# Ignoring whitespace in a custom environment

Tags: environments

I know there has been questions similar to this previously but none of the proposed solutions seem to work for me.

I have a few custom environments I am using in LaTeX. Below is the code for a "licenses" environment. This environment is basically a table and I use the "license" command to specify each row of the table.

```
\newenvironment{licenses}
{%
\def\lwidth{0.25\textwidth}%
\def\rwidth{0.69\textwidth}%
%
\newcommand\license[3]{%
\ifdef{\separator}{\separator}{}%
##1 & ##3 %
\def\separator{\\}%
}%
%
\begin{longtable}{>{\bfseries}L{\lwidth}!{\VRule}R{\rwidth}}%
}
{\end{longtable}}
```

I then use the environment as follows... however I have a problem in that the whitespace between each `\license` command affect the output.

```
\begin{licenses}
\license{...}{...}

\license{...}{...}

\license{...}{...}

\end{licenses}
```

I have tried the `\ignorespaces` command and also commands similar to `\catcode32=9\relax`, but none of these seem to work in my case.

Here is a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}           % for ifdef
\usepackage{longtable}          % for tables that span more than one page
\usepackage{tabularx}           % for newcolumntype
\usepackage{xcolor}             % for colours

\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedleft}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{p{#1}}
\newcommand\VRule{\color{lightgray}\vrule width 0.5pt}

\newenvironment{licenses}
 {%
\def\lwidth{0.25\textwidth}%
\def\rwidth{0.69\textwidth}%
%
\newcommand\license[3]{%
\ifdef{\separator}{\separator}{}%
##1 & ##3 %
\def\separator{\\}%
}%
%
\begin{longtable}{>{\bfseries}L{\lwidth}!{\VRule}R{\rwidth}}
}
{\end{longtable}}

\begin{document}
\section*{Licenses}
\begin{licenses}
\license{Test1}{Test1}{Test1}

\license{Test2}{Test2}{Test2}

\license{Test3}{Test3}{Test3}

\end{licenses}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that it is not "whitespace" but empty lines, which are converted to \par by tex. You can try redefining locally \par.

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Your code fragments don't seem to match: you define \licence to have three arguments (but it doesn't use `#2` ? but your use of \license only shows two arguments. Please post a complete document that shows the problem.

Comment: @PeterGrill - Sorry about that. Have included a MWE.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Yes, the second argument is intentionally not used. I wanted to store the data but (at this point in time) I don't really care about having it in the output.

Comment: Why are you defining `\license` in that way? A simple `\newcommand{\license}[3]{#1&#2\\}` outside the definition of `licenses` (or even inside it, with double `##`) will do, avoiding the blank lines.

Comment: @egreg. So it does! The reason for the use of separator used in this way is because (although in the process of debugging I removed it) I wanted a 0.5em space BETWEEN each table row, but not after the last row. So I originally defined separator to `\\[0.5em]` instead of just `\\`.Perhaps there is a better way to put spacing between table rows.?

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I have been looking for a [Command that gobbles all following empty lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55914/8057). The main idea is to define a command `\gobblepars` (taken from [this blog](http://phaseportrait.blogspot.com/2011/08/using-gobblepars-to-prevent-latex-from.html)):

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\gobblepars{%
    \@ifnextchar\par%
        {\expandafter\gobblepars\@gobble}%
        {}}
\makeatother
```

Does it work if you use this command as the very last command of the definition of your `\license` command?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: @joshua: if only one empty line is enough, look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24786/adding-extra-lines-spaces-in-source-not-affecting-semantics where I asked a similar question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that nothing goes in the `licenses` environment, a refinement of user946850's idea can work:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{longtable}          % for tables that span more than one page
\usepackage{xcolor}             % for colours

\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedleft}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{p{#1}}
\newcommand\VRule{\color{lightgray}\vrule width 0.5pt}

\newcommand{\license}[3]{%
  #1 & #3 \bingo
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\bingo{%
  \@ifnextchar\par
    {\expandafter\bingo\@gobble}
    {\@ifnextchar\end{}{\\[2ex]}}}
\makeatother
\newenvironment{licenses}
 {%
  \def\lwidth{0.25\textwidth}%
  \def\rwidth{0.69\textwidth}%
  \begin{longtable}{>{\bfseries}L{\lwidth}!{\VRule}R{\rwidth}}
}
{\end{longtable}}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\section*{Licenses}
\begin{licenses}

\license{Test1}{Test1}{Test1}

\license{Test2}{Test2}{Test2}

\license{Test3}{Test3}{Test3}

\end{licenses}
\end{document}
```